# Why my script is stop running when i put a variable in foreach and for loop

Tags: javascript, php

When i put

```
$link15 = $link15.$U;
$newpdf1 =  $newpdf1.$_SESSION['arrayvalue']."\r\n\r\n".$link15."\r\n\r\n";
$link15 = "";
```

this line of code in foreach/for loop the the script is stop after displaying one result. and when i remove this line of code it runs.
Below is the complete script:

```
 for ($i = 0, $count = count($arr1); $i < $count; $i++) {
    print $arr1[$i]."\r\n\r\n";
    $_SESSION['arrayvalue'] = "$arr1[$i]";
    $in = $arr1[$i];
    $in = str_replace(' ','+',$in); // space is a +
     $result15 = httpGet("https://www.google.com/cse?cx=003255331468891741234:xxxxxxxxxx&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q='.$in.'&oq='.$in.'");
    //echo $result15;
    //this is to get perticular tag/node value 
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    $dom->loadXML($result15);
    $N = $dom->getElementsByTagName('U');
    foreach ($N as $U) {
       echo $U->nodeValue, PHP_EOL."<br/>";
       $link15 = $link15.$U;
    }
    $newpdf1 =  $newpdf1.$_SESSION['arrayvalue']."\r\n\r\n".$link15."\r\n\r\n";
    $link15 = "";
 }
```

Where i am doing error in concatenation or any other error.
Thank You!

Comment: Why is Javascript tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, $U is an object, yet you're trying to concatenate it to $link15.

Try changing this:

$link15 = $link15.$U;

To this:

$link15 = $link15.$U->nodeValue;

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate an object with a string

try the below code (what I have changed is I am accessing the particular key named as "nodeValue" in your $U object. If you want to add another change it accordingly, you need to access the particular key or bunch of keys depending on your requirement)

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($arr1); $i < $count; $i++) 
{
print $arr1[$i]."\r\n\r\n";
$_SESSION['arrayvalue'] = "$arr1[$i]";
$in = $arr1[$i];
$in = str_replace(' ','+',$in); // space is a +
 $result15 = httpGet("https://www.google.com/cse?cx=0032553314688917412345:xxxxxxxxx&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q='.$in.'&oq='.$in.'");
//echo $result15;
//this is to get perticular tag/node value 
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($result15);
$N = $dom->getElementsByTagName('U');
foreach ($N as $U) {
   echo $U->nodeValue, PHP_EOL."<br/>";
   // here you need to access the particular key or bunch of keys depending on your requirement
   $link15 = $link15.$U->nodeValue;
            }
$newpdf1 =  $newpdf1.$_SESSION['arrayvalue']."\r\n\r\n".$link15."\r\n\r\n";
$link15 = "";

}
```

Hope this helps.